# Unexpected Error on approval workflow in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, approval-process

I am attempting to implement a calendar approval workflow and two of the approvers seem to be having issues accessing the task to approve the item.  Right now I have an email that is sent to the approver with a link to the task FormURN.   When they click on the link in the email however they get

> An unexpected error has occurred.

[image]with a correlation ID and that's it.  They also get the same error if they try to hit the direct URL to the task as well.

I have confirmed that these two approvers have designer access to both the calendar and the task list involved.  Everyone else seems to be having no issues.  I have also ruled out that it's a location issue as other users in the same location have no issue.  The correlation ID is not showing up in the workflow history and I am not seeing any errors in the workflow history reports.

I currently have it so it sets a variable called Approvers based on the Department chosen:

`Set Variable: Approvers to <domain>\<userID>`

It then starts an out of the box approval workflow which has been heavily customized using the variable:

`Start Time Off Approval process on Current Item with Variable: Approvers`

I am using SharePoint 2010 Designer for the workflow.  I am also able to hit the form without issue by clicking on the email link as well.

As I only have designer access I have requested a ticket to be opened to look up the correlation ID on SharePoint Foundation but no response yet from the team that manages that server.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future problems, download the uls viewer where you have a realtime logging and the possibility to filter by correlationId

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was due to a task permissions issue after all.  After I unchecked "Only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks" it no longer had an issue. Thanks.